# CoreData Selecting All Rows in Association One-by-one When Persisting to Disk

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm using a parent-child MOC architecture as described by Marcus Zarra in his [blog post](http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/03/core-data-stack/) and [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ckbke8vjHMw).

It's generally working great, but I have an ordered one-to-many relationship where the "many" accumulates a lot of records over time. The issue is, in the process of saving the private context to disk, CoreData runs a select query for what appears to be every single object in the association, one at a time, even if it hasn't been touched. As you can imagine, this is incredibly slow.

Any ideas on how to eliminate this or at least make it batch it into one query?

Comment: Zarra's book might assist, from The Pragmatic Bookshelf – "Core Data, 2nd Edition, Data Storage and Management for iOS, OS X, and iCloud" (Jan 2013), in particular Chapter 4 titled Performance Tuning.

Comment: Define a lot. Explain how you tested to find this out. Show the code that edits it.

Answer (score 0):

Ordered relationships are problematic for a number of reasons, but this is out of scope for this question.

One obvious solution attempt is to replicate the ordered property yourself by introducing your own attribute to keep track of the order. This is the path I have taken in all my projects where I had this use case. Your own ordering logic gives you much more granular control over the expensive processes, such as inserting an element into the series (rather than just appending it at the end).

Please note that in many applications the ordered property can be modeled differently, e.g. with a time stamp, which in some cases can spare you the necessity of modifying the whole chain.

As for the problem of using "one query": You could fetch all objects needing to be reordered, modifying their order (e.g. by adding them one by one to the parent object), and save.

Comment: Thanks. I've been thinking of just managing the whole relationship on my own, but was hoping I could figure out how to use the out of the box functionality. Sounds like doing it on my own might be the way to go long term.